# Is it ok to skip hasOwnProperty() when checking Object.prototype first?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-in-loop, hasownproperty

We are supposed to use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) when iterating over the keys of an object because `Object.prototype` may be polluted, which through prototype inheritance, will also pollute the keys of all objects.

So if I don't pollute `Object.prototype`, I should be able to skip `hasOwnProperty()` which slows down the [for-in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). It will also make the code simpler.

**Idea: first check that `Object.prototype` is not polluted, then don't use `hasOwnProperty()`.**

Checking that `Object.prototype` was not polluted is done by the following function. I will call this in a strategic place in my code which is executed occasionally during the script execution (like before I am going to process a bunch of datas). This function is merely a guard alerting me if anything bad was done to `Object.prototype`:

```
/* jshint -W089 */  // http://jslinterrors.com/the-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statement/
var checkObjectPrototypeNotAugmented = function() {
    /* jshint unused:false */   // Because key is considered unused
    // Check if there is any enumerable property on Object.prototype:
    for(var key in Object.prototype) {
        throw new Error("Object.prototype has been augmented with keys: " + Object.prototype.keys());
    }
};
```

*Note: I put the `/* jshint -W089 */` comment so that jshint wont [complain about missing `hasOwnProperty()`](http://jslinterrors.com/the-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statement/).*

**Question: Is this ok ? Is there anything else I should be careful about ? Or that I can improve ?**

---

**Now some benchmarks:**

Here are 3 jsPerf benchmarks which show the gains for objects with different numbers of properties:

- 1 property: [Iterate own keys of plain objects with 1 property](http://jsperf.com/iterate-own-keys-of-plain-objects-with-1-property)
- 10 properties: [Iterate own keys of plain objects with 10 properties](http://jsperf.com/iterate-own-keys-of-plain-objects-with-10-properties)
- 100 properties: [Iterate own keys of plain objects with 100 properties](http://jsperf.com/iterate-own-keys-of-plain-objects-with-100-properties)

Note: the `Object.prototype` check is executed each time the properties of an object are going to be iterated. In a real situation, the test needs only to be performed once: when the full page is loaded (and then from time to time to be sure that no script inadvertently modified `Object.prototype`). So in real situation, you would get the performance of the "Reference" test. But this shows that even when always performing the test, it stays faster.

Interesting results:

- not using `hasOwnProperty()` either gives the same speed or is faster depending on the browser
- even when accessing **only 1** property, checking `Object.protoype` before each for-in loop can be faster in some browser than `hasOwnProperty()` ! (But I don't recommend always checking `Object.prototype` like this)

*Related: we see also that using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) can be even faster in some browsers for large objects, but it can also be slower for small objects. But using `Object.keys()` forces you to either only support browsers >= IE 9, or to augment the `Object.prototype` with a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) in IE <= 8. So for old browser compatibility, you would have to choose either `Object.keys()` or `checkObjectPrototypeNotAugmented()`.*